# Maintain stable data in a database

Tags: mysql, performance, performance-testing

I am doing Performance evaluation of my application. The size of database is around 20GB. I am using jMeter as a performance evaluation tool. Here each performance test (ie., Each jMeter run) there is some number of records are inserted. Here is my testing sequence.

1. Run jMeter and check the time taken to complete an action
2. Finetune the code for performance.
3. Re-Run the same scenario and check the timing.

For example.
 Before run :

```
Id      Name
1       XXXX
2       YYYY
3       ZZZZ
```

After Step 1, My table data look likes

```
Id      Name
1       XXXX
2       YYYY
3       ZZZZ
4       AAAA
5       BBBB
6       CCCC
..etc
```

Now I wants to revert my table like the first ie.,

```
Id      Name
1       XXXX
2       YYYY
3       ZZZZ
```

Here what my problem is the DB size is growing for each test run.

Is there any way to maintain some benchmark (if the DB size is 20GB means, It must be maintain the size as 20GB till end of my test). Any one please guide me how to achieve my requirement.

Comment: This question is hard to understand. You're likely to get better replies if you can rewrite it in a clearer way. Some more specific details about what you're testing and what you're trying to achieve might also be helpful.

Comment: Normally benchmarking is done with rolling back all changes after the run is finished, that is, the last statement of the test script is `ROLLBACK;`.  Of course, you have to write `BEGIN;` as the very first one.

Comment: @dezso, Thanks for your reply. When i run jmeter the data which is inserted are automatically committed then how can i rollback the transactions??

Comment: Can you turn off autocommit?  When committed, you can't roll back anymore.

Comment: Is all your data InnoDB ? Do you have `innodb_file_per_table` enabled? Please run SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'innodb_file_per_table';

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA in my database innodb_file_per_table is set as ON...

Comment: You are adding data. Of course the size is going to change.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really have the possibility to try jMeter now, so I don't know how following the below advice would affect your tests.

Normally benchmarking is done so that after the tests the original database state is restored.  This is achieved by rolling back all changes.

In the case of jMeter you have to set `AutoCommit` to false in the JDBC configuration, then issue a `ROLLBACK` as the very last command in your test script.

Comment: I am using rails application. So i am couldn't use Rollback or savepoint.

Comment: @Bathakarai well any framework that won't allow you to control your transactions sounds like something that you should run away from ... quickly.